# Refresh A View/Partial View without using Ajax or Submit in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel which contains Different Type of List

When first time page is loaded, I wanted to display the List of Data against the drop-down selected.

When the Drop-Down Changes then I want to display List of Data specific to that type.

But I don't want to go to my Controller, as in that Case I need to do the search/query, where as I already have all the types in my View at first.

How Can I Do that?

Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to go to the server(ajax\submit) then you will need to download all the data(in the first response) and change the list using javascript.

When the select box's [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) occurs, you javascript will need to get the selected value and update the new list to work against it.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<select id="s1"></select>
<select id="s2"></select>
```

JS:

```
var currData = ["1", "2", "3"];
var otherData = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i"]
]


for (var i = 0; i < currData.length; i++) {
    var option = $('<option value="' + currData[i] + '">' + currData[i] + '</option>');
    $("#s1").append(option);
}
// s1 and s2 are the same when the page loads.
$('#s2').html($('#s1').html());

$('#s1').change(function () {
    var idx = currData.indexOf($(this).val());
    var newSelectData = otherData[idx]; // change s2 due to s1's selection
    $('#s2').children().remove(); // clear the s2 select box
    for (var i = 0; i < newSelectData.length; i++) {
        var option = $('<option value="' + newSelectData[i] + '">' + newSelectData[i] + '</option>');
        $("#s2").append(option);
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5fymo1rq/)**.

Comment: You Mean display all data at first and hide the unwanted data?
and use hide/show in jquery?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, That would be the only way without calling your controller, but why do you not want to do that?

Comment: I've edited and added a small example. I'm not sure this is exactly what you wanted but it will help you understand how you should do this.

Comment: The problem is when I Use ajax, then I value does not persist from one view to another for more than once.
one time it can be achieved using TempData.